# Batch with comments in OrientDB Studio

Tags: comments, orientdb

I want to run a batch of queries, mostly creating and dropping indexes. In the batch call I also have a bunch of comments but the query parser keeps failing because of the comments. How do I write a comment?

I basically want to do this:

```
DROP INDEX oldIndex
/* 
Comments
*/
CREATE INDEX newIndex ON Class (field) NOTUNIQUE
```

I have tried to comment with //, -- and #.
I also tried placing everything inside a transaction with begin and end but I can't drop an index inside a transaction.

Note that I'm using the **studio**. I made short test in the console but I still got problem with comments and lacked the overview to see any problems with my queries.

I am guessing the problem has to do with each row is seen as its own command. I suppose a command with only a comment doesn't make sense but is there any way around it?

Comment: Hi, I tried your example and I have the same problem, a possibly work-around could be execute row by row highlighting them. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that was I was thinking. Was hoping for a more complete method but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried from Studio

[image]

I have found this issue https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/4651 about your problem with comments.
If the problem persists, you can reopen the issue.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, use `#` comment-lines, that is, lines in which the first character (or the first non-blank character) is `#`.

I have used this in console.sh scripts in Version 2.1.x, e.g. 2.1.9, 2.1.10, and 2.1.11.